# Prevent user access to a folder that he creates

Tags: c#, windows, security

Hello stackoverflow community,

I developed a program in C# that creates a directory in `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\DIRECTORY_NAME` and `.txt` files inside the directory. When the program is run it opens `.txt` files and the program writes text, when the user `USERNAME` closes the program also `.txt` files are closed.

Is it possible to prevent the user `USERNAME` from accessing the folder `DIRECTORY_NAME`? The solution must avoid that the program run by `USERNAME` can write in `.txt` files.

Any ideas?
Thank you

Comment: You want to create a program that can create files but not write to them? Perhaps you should explain what is the *actual* problem? For example, app.config files are already read-only. They are created when the application is deployed.

Comment: If the user has an administrator account on the machine, all you can do is place obstacles, not absolutely prevent access. So, what is the nature of these users?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I want that only the program can write to the file, i don't want that USERNAME go to directory DIRECTORY_NAME and can read/write created by the program

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever user dont' have administration account. User simply log in to computer and run programs already installed

Comment: From your response to Panagiotis, it sound like you want *programs* to have permissions. That's not part of the windows security model. *Users* have permissions. Any program run by a user can make use of that user's permissions. Perhaps you need to think about splitting your app into a client/service model and having the restricted parts running in the service (which runs under a different user account)

Comment: @DavideMosezon the program writes to the folder using the *user's* account. What do you actually want to do? What is written in those files and why do you worry that the user is going to go into AppData to modify them? Perhaps you should look into Isolated Storage? It doesn't prevent modifications but at least it obfuscates the path

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thank you for your answer, i know what you say but i hope that there are some tricks to avoid the rules of windows

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Because what program writes it could be hidden by users, crypting is only a part of the solution i don't want that user can delete or modify the files

Comment: You are still describing your attempted solution, not the problem. Applications are working just fine without program-level permissions. *Databases* for example run under a different service account. Installed programs are secure from user modifications because Windows itself detects changes to the components (ie files) installed with an MSI and repairs accidental deletions.

Comment: Using a separate service process and service account isn't much different from what you ask. It's more secure and manageable though. Programs can change or get replaced. A service account is well known. It can also be defined at the domain level, allowing centralized management